# Get week of month by date in SQL Server (need T-SQL function similar to C# function)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have been using a C# function to get the month of week and I need a similar function in T-SQL to get the same result.

```
public static int GetWeekNumberOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    date = date.Date;

    DateTime firstMonthDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

    var mon = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday;
    var dofw = (int)firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek;

    DateTime firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);

    if (firstMonthMonday > date)
    {
        firstMonthDay = firstMonthDay.AddMonths(-1);
        firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    }

    return (date - firstMonthMonday).Days / 7 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Any effort on the sql side?

Comment: i need the exact conversion of c# function to mssql

Comment: In which context do you need "Week X of September" where X=1 is the first week which starts inside September? This is an odd notation, are you sure your users will be familiar with this? What week is 1st of September then? Week 5 of August?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d = '2015-10-20'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @d)  -
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,@d), 0))+ 1 AS WEEK_OF_MONTH
```

Comment: if we use date @d = '2015-9-30' then it reurns week no 5 but actually its week no 4

Comment: @Ravi:- No, considering '2015-9-1' as starting of week and as week 1 then  week 1 ends on '2015-9-3' and then week 2 starts.

Comment: :- i need starting of week from Monday

Comment: @Ravi:- So in that case '2015-09-05' would be week 1 of September?